# Why don't I have many side quests in the early game?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm new to The Witcher. I have gone to every `?` on the first world map, took all contracts from the board and reached level 3.9. (I'm playing on highest difficulty level)

Then, when I finally progressed in the main story, I got a shave and went to pick the next world map to explore. However, it suggests recommended level be 5. But I don't know where else to go to get more XP. There are no quests left to do and farming is barely giving any XP.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not quite clear where you are at the moment. Are you in the royal palace at Vizima and have you talked to the emperor and Yen?

Comment: Yes I talked to the Emporer and Yen and have to find that girl.  So very early on. I did some research, apparently the game forces you to play against higher levels, so best is to be well prepared.  Levels can't be matched by the look of it.

Comment: I would advise turning off the ? markers on the map once you get to Velen. You'll have plenty to do without running around doing busywork like those, and you'll encounter plenty of them through the course of play anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next area (Velen) is very large and has a big variety of quests and creatures at all different levels. You should not have too much difficultly leveling up - just do plenty of saves!

Taking on quests and creatures that are slightly above your level will give more level points.

The most experience always comes from the main story quests. If I remember correctly the first part of the main story in Velen doesn't involve much fighting.

Be sure to use all your ability points in the character page to build up Geralt's skills.